# Compress image, using imageScalr

Tags: java, image, compression, image-scaling, imgscalr

I am using imagescalr for resizing images, but i also want to compress the images so that the size stays below 32kb(as ie 8 supports base64 strings upto 32kb). I am resizing the image like this

```
Map resizeImage(BufferedImage imageData, int width, int height, String imageFormat){

    BufferedImage thumbnail =  Scalr.resize(imageData, Scalr.Method.SPEED, Scalr.Mode.FIT_EXACT ,
    width, height, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ImageIO.write(thumbnail, imageFormat, baos)
    baos.flush()
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray()
    baos.close()

    return [imageBytes:imageBytes, imageFormat:imageFormat]
}
```

I want a way so that i can compress with least change to the code.

Comment: *"(as ie 8 supports base64 strings up to 32kb)"*  Interesting.  I have so far found several use-cases for encoding images as base 64 strings, both for easy display of client side generated images in the browser, to an 'undo/redo' facility for a paint app.  What is the use case here?

Comment: I have images in the form of blobs in the database, for displaying them in the browser i am converting them to base64 strings on the server and sending them over to the browser, now i have two use cases 1. Showing thumbnail(which is 150X150 image), so size usually stays below 32kb and it displays properly 2. Showing an enlarged version of the image when user clicks on the thumbnail, this needs to be atleast 500X344, and that's where the problem is. So i basically want to compress the image along with the resize, Imagescalr doesn't provide any such option out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
ImageIO.write(thumbnail, imageFormat, baos)
gzip.close();
byte[] zippedImageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

unzipping

```
InputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zippedImageBytes));
....
```